# Newrelic AttributeError: _nr_database_name

Tags: python, newrelic

Newrelic is showing this error:

```
2015-11-05 01:26:38 ERROR newrelic.core.application The generation of transaction data has failed. This would indicate some sort of internal implementation issue with the agent. Please report this problem to New Relic support for further investigation.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/newrelic-2.56.0.42-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/newrelic/core/application.py", line 776, in record_transaction
stats.record_transaction(data)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/newrelic-2.56.0.42-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/newrelic/core/internal_metrics.py", line 82, in __call__
return self.__wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/newrelic-2.56.0.42-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/newrelic/core/stats_engine.py", line 743, in record_transaction
self.record_time_metrics(transaction.time_metrics(self))
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/newrelic-2.56.0.42-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/newrelic/core/stats_engine.py", line 412, in record_time_metrics
for metric in metrics:
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/newrelic-2.56.0.42-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/newrelic/core/transaction_node.py", line 161, in time_metrics
for metric in child.time_metrics(stats, self, self):
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/newrelic-2.56.0.42-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/newrelic/core/function_node.py", line 70, in time_metrics
for metric in child.time_metrics(stats, root, self):
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/newrelic-2.56.0.42-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/newrelic/core/database_node.py", line 132, in time_metrics_r2
product = self.product
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/newrelic-2.56.0.42-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/newrelic/core/database_node.py", line 45, in product
return self.dbapi2_module._nr_database_name
AttributeError: _nr_database_name
```

Was implemented using:

```
import newrelic.agent
newrelic.agent.initialize('path_of/newrelic.ini')
```

Because plone wasn't working with run-program or run-python method